# How to get the string value from a Enumerable.Any and List.Contains comparison?

Tags: c#, string, list, comparison

I have 2 string lists that I am checking if List 1 contains any of the items in List 2.

```
if (List2.Any(s => List1.Contains(s)))
{ //do stuff 
}
```

If a string is found, I am wanting to log it, but I cannot find a way to get the value of S from the above code.

When I try to write out 'S' as a variable for a string, it isn't recognized as one.

How can I get the value of S from my above comparison?

Also - I couldn't figure out how to put into words specifically what I was after for the title. If you have a recommendation on how to re-write the Title, I'm open to it. I'd like it to be accurate for the question.

Comment: Given the following inputs, what should the output be? `List1 = {1, 2, 2, 3}` and `List2 = {2, 3, 3, 4}` Should it be `{2, 3, 3}`, `{2, 3}` or something else?

Comment: Use a plain foreach loop instead. Clearer and you can access all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.Any` isn't meant to get what's being found but just *that something was found*.

If you also want *what was found*, I believe you should use `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`:

```
string result = list2.FirstOrDefault(s => list1.Contains(s));

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

In the other hand, if you want all coincidences, you should use `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```
IEnumerable<string> allCoincidences = list2.Intersect(list1);
```

Answer (score -1):

This Linq will do what you need in just one line

```
if ((from s in List2 from s1 in List1 where s == s1 select s).Any())
{
  //do stuff 
}
```